# Disabling 'Move Component' in Experience Editor for a specific rendering

Tags: experience-editor

Is it possible to disable an option, Move Component, in the Experience Editor, for a specific rendering?

I have looked at the rendering and rendering options, but neither gave the possibility. I have also looked into user rights, but to no avail.

I have attached a picture of the button:

[image: Move Component button]

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? You don't want the rendering to be moved to another placeholder or you don't want the rendering to be moved at all? In case of the latter, what do you expect if another rendering is added and moved before or after the _sticky_ rendering? Or what if the user removes and adds the _sticky_ rendering? These actions may alter the order of your _sticky_ rendering as well.

Comment: I do not want the rendering to be moved at all. I realized that this could be circumvented by enthustiastic authors. The so called _sticky_ rendering is part of the page template. I value your valid concerns, and will take it into my considerations.

Comment: you try: remove all items in "Allowed Controls" of placeholder settings. so all sublayout or rendering can add this placehoder. I do and it have worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Pipeline Method:***

*Option 1:*
Deep in the bowels of Experience Editor, you will find that eventually, the Move Component button is enabled/disabled based on the Allowed Renderings set on the placeholder. You could add a processor to the **getPlaceholderRenderings** to weed out the rendering you are looking for so that it acts like a static rendering. But keep in mind, that will cause Experience Editor to act like you can't put more of that control in the placeholder.

*Option 2:* Another Pipeline called **getChromeData** is what Experience Editor uses to control almost the entirety of the look and feel of itself. This controls the features for placeholders, fields, edit frames, and sublayouts/renderings.  **Mucking with a processor in this option might be the best from an upgrade-ability point of view**

***God-Mode Method:***

For more control over the use of the options in Experience Editor, like the Move Component, another option is to create your own click method and either change the default rendering button, or create your own button.

You can achieve this by looking in the Core Database and finding this item:
[image: Move Component Button in Core DB]

The particular `chrome:rendering:sort` command is actually handled in the RenderingChromeType.js file in the "Page Modes" application within the /sitecore/shell directory.

```
 handleMessage: function(message, params, sender) {
switch (message) {
  case "chrome:rendering:sort":
    this.sort();
    break;
```

You can augment this Javascript file to do what you want.  ***However***, beware that editing this javascript file could lead to upgrade stress in the future.

Another option that could be available to you is to create your own custom command, and patch it in. For example, if you set the click to be `chrome:common:edititem({command:"webedit:validatesortablerendering"})` where `webedit:validatesortablerendering` is a custom command that you patch in, you can test the rendering type first (basically it would be the template type of the datasource item).  If this is not a rendering that can be sorted, then abort further action.  If it is, then call the Sitecore Javascript trigger to act on the event `chrome:rendering:sort`

***In Summary:***

There are a few ways to shave this yak. I think **Pipeline Method Option 2** might be the best option, but it really depends on what your overall objective is and how destructive you want to be to Sitecore.

Answer (score 3):

To disable editing of the specific rendering, you can Uncheck the `Editable` field on the rendering item.

When `Editable` is unchecked floating toolbar will not show up for that rendering.

Note that this option will keep allowing authors to edit the content in the rendering.

[image: Sitecore Sample Rendering]

Answer (score 2):

**One simple option could be:** If you only allow that rendering for a specific placeholder when you click on move, you won't see any `Move to here`. Not as nice, but the same effect.