# disable move/add/delete component for specific placeholder in Experience Editor via code

Tags: jss, experience-editor

In my NextJS/JSS/TS site, I am rendering the same placeholder twice within a single component. I would like to make one of the placeholders read only in the sense that components within it cannot be moved, added, or deleted. Ideally, this would be a code change; that is:

```
<Placeholder
  name="feed-sections"
  rendering={props.rendering}

  // Ideally I would be able to do something like this
  // editable={false}
/>
```

This question was inspired by a similar question for MVC implementations:

[Disabling 'Move Component' in Experience Editor for a specific rendering](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/50/disabling-move-component-in-experience-editor-for-a-specific-rendering)

What methods are available for doing something similar in modern JSS solutions?

Comment: The same things that are available in MVC are available for you in JSS.